# How do I compare 2 sets of rows from the same table (Oracle 12c)

Tags: sql, comparison, row, version, oracle12c

in the table below I want to compare for each `user_id` whether the number of rows for `security_privilege_id` has changed.

I want to compare latest`version_number` with `version_number` before `last_update` = '01.03.2020'.

So in the example below, I want to show that for user_id = 9867 the number of rows changed from 8 to 6.

I'm trying to see this output for the example. It shows the security privileges which are missing from the latest `version_number`.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image: sample data]

[image: sample output]

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: Also, why aren't you considering the version number 15, and instead comparing 16 to 14?

Comment: Just added the output which I'm trying to get.

Comment: Regarding the version, I'm only interested in the version before last_update = 01.03.2020. The previous version is not reliable for me.

Comment: What do you mean by *before last_update = 01.03.2020*? Your data does not show that date.

Comment: It's the first column on the right side of the table. The previous version has to be before 01.03.2020. You can see that's why I'm not using version 15, but instead using version 14 and then comparing it with version 16.

Comment: I don't get the significance of date `01.03.2020`. Why this date ? Do you mean its just a hard coded value ? Don't you need a generalized query or just the use case you have mentioned ?

Comment: What about the other way around , some new `security_privilege_id` newly introduced in `version 16` which were no there `version 14` ?

Comment: That output will be fine as well. Basically take the delta between the two rows, and show what's new in version 16.

Comment: The date 01.03.2020 is a cut-off date I use because ONLY after this date I'm expecting that the security privileges have been recently changed.